# download local html file on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, relative-path

I have a local file called test.html. The path to this file (relative) is "../slides/test.html".

I would like to :

- Have a button to download this file
- Have a button to open this file in a new tab

How can i do these 2 things ?

I tried to get the file with ajax, i get data object containing html code of the file, but i don't know how to do to download and opening this file.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../slides/test.html",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

I solve the problem by doing this :

```
<ul class="buttonsList">
    <li><a href="#" id="fullscreenBtn">View in fullScreen</a></button></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="downloadBtn" download>Download</a></button></li>
</ul>

// Register click on download button
$("#downloadBtn").off().on('click', function() {
    var slideURL = $(".helpActive").attr("data-textTour-url");
    $('#downloadBtn').attr({href  : slideURL});
});

// Register click on download button
$("#fullscreenBtn").off().on('click', function() {
    var slideURL = $(".helpActive").attr("data-textTour-url");
    $('#fullscreenBtn').attr({target: '_blank', href  : slideURL});
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download File Using Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749231/download-file-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: Maybe OT, but this can be interesting for you https://programmingistheway.wordpress.com/2015/04/16/saving-file-from-the-client-side-with-the-save-as-logic/

Comment: The way to make this functionality cross-browser with all compatibility is to set a header server-side (like PHP) to force download. The open in new tab is a basic '90s html feature.

Comment: [filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For download

```
<a href="path-to-file" download>Download</a>
```

For open in new tab

```
<a href="path-to-file" target="_blank">Open in new tab</a>
```

Comment: Please, see that: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download . Mobile support is nothing. Desktop support is precary

Comment: Is there download attribute for a tag?

Comment: Yes, it exists, but the compatibility is poor. Nothing to do in IE or mobile (iOS and Android). Only works in FF, Chrome and Edge